# HTML how do a condition: if checkbox was ever changed

Tags: php, html, checkbox

i have an html file like this:

```
<article class="question">
    <input id="revert" name ="revert" type="checkbox">
    <label for="revert">
        <section  class="front">
            <?php echo $question ?>
        </section>

        <section class="back">
            <?php echo $answer ?>
        </section>
    </label>
</article>

<form method="post">
    <input type=text name="reponse" placeholder="Ecrivez votre réponse ici"/>
    <input type=submit name="envoi_reponse" id="envoi_reponse_1" value="Envoyer"/>
</form>
```

i want to see in PHP, if the checkbox "revert" was changed or not,
i don't want to see if it's checked, i need to know if it was ever changed.
So if the user check it, and then uncheck then the condition = true

Maybe with some javascript ? I don't know js but i can try to use it, if it's not super hard

Comment: This would need to be done in client side.

Comment: Is your check box saved in  `$question`, if fo please add this code to your question.

Comment: ```$question```  contain only text to display, ignore that, it don't contain anything usefull.
And how to that client side ? what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will help:

```
<script>
    $('#input-to-watch').on('change', function() {
        var checked = false;
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checked = true;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handle_change_checkbox.php',
            data: {checkboxState: checked},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(res) {
                alert(res);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('error!!!');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

and this will be your **handle_change_checkbox.php**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (!empty($_POST['checkboxState'])) {
        if ($_POST['checkboxState'] == true) {
            die ('checkbox is changed to checked');
        }else {
            die ('checkbox is changed to not checked');
        }
    }
    die ('something went wrong, check your posted data');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var isCheckboxChanged = false;
var checkboxInitialValue = $('#revert').is(":checked");
var checkboxValueAfterChange = null ;
$('#revert').on('change', function(){
    isCheckboxChanged = true;
    checkboxValueAfterChange = $('#revert').is(":checked");
    $('#wasValueChanged').val(1);
    if(checkboxValueAfterChange == null){
        console.log("No Changes detected");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Checkbox state is the same after change ?");
        console.log(checkboxInitialValue == checkboxValueAfterChange);
    }
    
    $.ajax({
    url: "do_action_on_checkbox_revert.php", 
    success: function(result){
      $('.input_to_be_rendered_on_condition').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.more_you_want_to_add_dynamically').html(result.information);
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="revert">
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="wasValueChanged" value="0">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div class="hidden input_to_be_rendered_on_condition">
  <p>Some stuff that is here</p>
  <div class="more_you_want_to_add_dynamically"></div>
</div>
<!-- Later in PHP File (do_action_on_checkbox_revert.php) --> 
<!--
$reverted = false;
if(isset($_POST['wasValueChanged']) && $_POST['wasValueChanged'] > 0){
    $reverted=true;
}
$return_arr = array();
if($reverted){
  $return_arr["information"] = "We like changing input boxes";
}
else{
  $return_arr["information"] = "We hate changing input boxes";
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
-->

<!-- You cannot use the PHP part if thee submit button is not clicked, when you submit the form this page should reload and the $reverted should be true
```

You could use javascript for that. 
If you are only interested in if it has been ever clicked and changed, but it does not matter if the value stays the same at the end or not, you could use the following:

```
var isCheckboxChanged = false;
$('#revert').on('change', function(){
    isCheckboxChanged = true;
});
```

If it matters that the value is different then the one that you began with, you could do the following:

```
var checkboxInitialValue = $('#revert').is(":checked");
var checkboxValueAfterChange = null ;
$('#revert').on('change', function(){
    checkboxValueAfterChange = $('#revert').is(":checked");
    if(checkboxValueAfterChange == null){
       console.log("No Changes detected");
    }
    else{
       console.log("Checkbox state is the same after change ?");
       console.log(checkboxInitialValue == checkboxValueAfterChange);
    }
});
```

Comment: After testing a bit, i noticed, that when i send the form without touching the checkbox, it consider like it was changed.

I also changed it so i can check if it was changed in php (for other tests):
```<?php $reverted = false;?>
    $('#revert').on('change', function(){
        <?php $reverted = true;?>
    });``` 
Maybe the problem is from here ?

Comment: You cannot write javascript and php in the same block.

Comment: I will add to my solution, if you'd like to know on php side weather the checkbox was checked or not but the solution would need you to submit the form

Comment: I just updated the solution, without this, there is not much another way that you could use. If you are trying to render something new, if the checkbox was ever checked and you want it to happen right on the click of the checkbox, you would need AJAX. basically AJAX sends a request to PHP file which can return some data back and you could use javascript to format dom, insert the data as needed and then render it.

Comment: Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a toggle to set the instance when user first clicks the checkbox, then set that value in a variable and see if that value is greater than 0 and your checkbox is equal to false... This means the user clicked the checkbox once and then un-selected it after.

```js
function isChecked() {
  var valueCheck = document.querySelector('#checkBox:checked') !== null;
  var curValue = document.getElementById("checkBox").checked;
  console.log('Is the box checked?: ' + curValue)
  let i = 0;
  if (valueCheck) {
    i++;
    $checkNum = i;
  }
  if ($checkNum > 0 && curValue === false) {
    // do something when element was set but is now unset
    console.log('The box was set and now it has changed to false.' + '\nCheck: ' + valueCheck + '\nChange: ' + curValue);

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="isChecked()" name="checkBox" id="checkBox">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler:

```
<article class="question">
    <input onclick="changed()" id="revert" name="revert" type="checkbox">   <label>Changed: <b id="change">False</b></label>
    <label for="revert">
        <section  class="front">
            <?php echo $question ?>
        </section>

        <section class="back">
            <?php echo $answer ?>
        </section>
    </label>
</article>

<form method="post">
    <input type=text name="reponse" placeholder="Ecrivez votre réponse ici"/>
    <input type=submit name="envoi_reponse" id="envoi_reponse_1" value="Envoyer"/>
</form>
<script>
    function changed()
    {
        document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = 'true';
    }
</script>
```